# How to merging df2 into df1 and fill in NaNs while merging?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `df1, df2`.

`df1` has the columns `["id", "time", "cost", "quantity]`.

`df2` has the columns `["id", "time", "modified_cost", "modified_quantity]`.

I would like to merge `df2` into `df1`. Currently I am doing

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2["id", "time", "modified_cost", "modified_quantity"], on=["id", "time"], how="left")
```

But this ends up filling in NaNs if `df2` doesn't have the same set of `["id", "time"]` as `df1`. Instead of this, I would like for those NaNs to be the unmodified quantities.

here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4], "time": [3, 4, 5, 6], "cost": [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "quantity": [10,20,30,40]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [2,3,4], "time": [4, 5, 6], "modified_cost": [2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "modified_quantity": [20,30,40]}) 

df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=["id", "time"], how="left")

print(df1)
```

gives

```
   id  time  cost  quantity  modified_cost  modified_quantity
0   1     3   1.1        10            NaN                NaN
1   2     4   2.2        20            2.2               20.0
2   3     5   3.3        30            3.3               30.0
3   4     6   4.4        40            4.4               40.0
```

Instead of this, I want the NaNs to become whatever is in the `cost` and `quantity` column, so

```
   id  time  cost  quantity  modified_cost  modified_quantity
0   1     3   1.1        10            1.1                10.0
1   2     4   2.2        20            2.2               20.0
2   3     5   3.3        30            3.3               30.0
3   4     6   4.4        40            4.4               40.0
```

How can I achieve this behavior when merging?

Currently, the only solution I am aware of is to do this post merging

```
df1.loc[df1.modified_cost.isna(), "modified_cost"] = df1[df1.modified_cost.isna()].cost
```

Comment: For the desire output, where is your modified_quantity 20.0 comes from for ID 1?

Comment: @xiaochuanfang SOrry it should be 10.0. it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on filling a dataframe with another dataframe values.

I use `fillna` for this.

```py
r = (df1[['cost', 'quantity']] \
     .rename(columns=dict(zip(df1.columns[2:4], df1.columns[-2:])))
     )
df1.loc[:, df1.columns[-2:]] = df1[df1.columns[-2:]].fillna(r)

print(df1)
```

```
   id  time  cost  quantity  modified_cost  modified_quantity
0   1     3   1.1        10            1.1               10.0
1   2     4   2.2        20            2.2               20.0
2   3     5   3.3        30            3.3               30.0
3   4     6   4.4        40            4.4               40.0
```

**Speed time**

Testing of the strategy described above.

```py
import time

start = time.time()
# ...
end = time.time()

print(end-start) # 0.016285171508789062 seconds (on my computer)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you show a way to post-process the results of merge() to get the desired result. There are also ways to pre-process df2 using mask() to get the desired results, but they are not necessarily any better than your solution.

For example, you can do this:

```python
idTime = ['id','time']
df1 = df1.set_index(idTime)
df2 = df2.set_index(idTime).reindex(df1.index)
df1 = df1.merge(df2.mask(df2.isna(), df1.to_numpy()), on=idTime, how='left').reset_index()
```

... or this:

```python
df1 = ( df1.merge(
    df2.set_index(idTime).pipe(lambda d2, d1: 
        d2.reindex(d1.index).pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.isna(), d1.to_numpy())),
        df1.set_index(idTime)
    ).reset_index(), on=idTime, how="left") )
```

... or this:

```python
df1 = df1.set_index(idTime)
df2 = df2.set_index(idTime).reindex(df1.index)
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2.mask(df2.isna(), df1.to_numpy())], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Arguably, the last of the above is the most streamlined of the pre-processing strategies since after the call to reindex(), a call to merge() is really just used to append columns (rather than to do any database-style joining) which can be achieved using concat().

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find a way to achieve it within the `merge` function. But you can do post-processing in one line with `apply`. The idea is to replace 'modified_xxx'
with 'xxx'.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4], "time": [3, 4, 5, 6], "cost": [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "quantity": [10,20,30,40]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [2,3,4], "time": [4, 5, 6], "modified_cost": [2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "modified_quantity": [20,30,40]}) 

df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=["id", "time"], how="left").apply(lambda x:x.fillna(df1.loc[:,x.name.replace('modified_','')]))
```